# Access Insert Query

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert, autonumber

I am using C# to write/read to an Access 2007 Database. The table is
ID - AutoNumber [pkey]
Fname - Text
Lname - Text
Address - Text

The query string I Use is

```cs
"Insert into TblMain (Fname,Lname,Address) Values ('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+adrs+"')"
```

No errors are returned, the query executes but data is not added to the db.

Inserting to table using which does not have an autonumber data column works perfectly.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you using ADO.NET? Can you add data to any table? Perhaps post a code snippet in-case thats the issue, the query looks right...

Comment: the other thing is try running the query (e.g. `Insert into TblMain (Fname,Lname,Address) Values ('billy','bob','1 foo st')`) in the access query window and see if it gives you a more informative error, you may be using reserved words...

Comment: yes, using ADO.net, OleDB. I changed my approach thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use an alias for the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query while placing field names under square brackets.

I remember in old days I faced similar situation where one of my field name was "zone" (I think I remember correctly) and I could not figure out why ADO will not let the query run. Later on I found that their implementation of ADO library had some conflict with that field name.

Comment: thanks, but it didnt work.

Changed my approach to using MAX() to retrieve the highest value then increment and Insert

Comment: Max will probably cause issues... Use 'Select @@identity'... Can you pos the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try including the ID field and give unique ID numbers to the records being appended?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861.aspx

> If your destination table contains a
>   primary key, make sure you append
>   unique, non-Null values to the primary
>   key field or fields; if you do not,
>   the Microsoft Access database engine
>   will not append the records.
>
> If you append records to a table with
>   an AutoNumber field and you want to
>   renumber the appended records, do not
>   include the AutoNumber field in your
>   query. Do include the AutoNumber field
>   in the query if you want to retain the
>   original values from the field.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem [Insert Query]:
[Software: Access 2013]

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [tblquery] ([stdid], [stdname])" _
& "VALUES ( " & Me.txtID & ", " & Me.txtName & ")"
```

Comment: The original question (10 years old) is asking for a solution in [tag:c#], but this looks to be [tag:vb.net].  Might you please translate?

Comment: @dbc: It's not even VB.NET but VBA, and the syntax is still wrong. It should be deleted as well.